# R bivariate normal dmvnorm graph

Tags: r

So, I'm trying to graph a bi-variate normal centered at 12.5 and 7.5, but it's always off centered.  Really, I'm trying to sample from a bi-variate distribution and just graph it real fast to make sure it worked.  Also, when I switch mu in dmvnorm to 50's it will work.  I know that this is not the best code/graph, but it's formatted this why to try to figure out what happened.  I don't know if the mistake is in the sampling or in the graphing.  What is going on here?

```
library(mixtools)

x3<-seq(10,15,by=.05)
x4<-seq(5,10,by=.05)
y<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(x3)*length(x4),ncol=3)
dim(y)
counter<-1
for(i in seq(1,length(x3))){
  for(j in seq(1,length(x4))){
    #Change 12.5 and 7.5 to 50's will put it in the center
    y[counter,]<-c(dmvnorm(y=c(i,j),mu=c(12.5,7.5),sigma=matrix(c(1000,0,0,1000),nrow=2))*1000,x3[i],x4[j])
    counter<-counter+1
  }
}
plot(y[,2],y[,3],pch=16,col=rgb(0,y[,1],0,maxColorValue=(dmvnorm(y=c(12.5,7.5),mu=c(12.5,7.5),sigma=matrix(c(1000,0,0,1000),nrow=2))*1000)),asp=1,xlim=c(min(y[,2]),max(y[,2])),ylim=c(min(y[,3]),max(y[,3])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

1. `dmvnorm(y=c(i,j))` is wrong, you need to evaluate the density at `c(x3[i], x4[j])`.
2. I didn't read your `plot()` statement that carefully, but `plot()` only takes at most two variables (you have 3), you'll need to use something like `image()` or `levelplot()`.

Here's what you are looking for:

> ```
> library(lattice)                                                                    
> d <- expand.grid("x3" = seq(10, 15, .05), "x4" = seq(5, 10, .05))                   
> d$dens <- dmvnorm(as.matrix(d), mu = c(12.5, 7.5), sigma = diag(1000, 2))           
> levelplot(dens ~ x3 * x4, data = d)
> ```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  That was a pretty rookie mistake.  I didn't even think to look at the looping.  For the plot, the third variable is for color.  So, it makes close to the same image.